# javascript Date(), render from array of weekdays, index chosen by Date().getDay(), reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

charitable & wise responders, why isn't `{WEEK_DAYS[weekdayname.getDay()]}` at the bottom of the codeblock rendering the weekday depending on the day the user is on?

do I need to interpolate some of it? I have tried this mostly already

```
export const WEEK_DAYS = {
    Sun: "Sun",
    Mon: "Mon",
    Tue: "Tue",
    Wed: "Wed",
    Thu: "Thu",
    Fri: "Fri",
    Sat: "Sat"
}

class CalSlideDrawer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
      day: new Date().getDate(),
      month: +new Date().getMonth(),
      year: +new Date().getFullYear(),
    };
  }
// insert user generated state changes of the date in view
render() {
  const weekdayname = new Date(this.state.year, this.state.month, this.state.day);
  <div className="weekday">{WEEK_DAYS[weekdayname.getDay()]}</div>
}
```

as of asking `{WEEK_DAYS[weekdayname.getDay()]}` renders blank.

> Go to src>UIConainers>Calendar>CalSlideDrawer.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dijkstra-1c31n?fontsize=14

the CalSlideDrawer.js is found by top-left logo icon (after pressing the inbox icon if you're starting on the purple screen)

Thanks so much

Comment: `.getDay()` returns a number. Sapienti sat ;)

Comment: yessss i replaced Sun-Sat key with 0-6

Comment: Because of getday get days index and your json object doesnt have index, if you try to define weekdays=["sun","mon".....] then it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Date.getDat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns a number from 0-6 representing Sunday-Saturday. 
 Change your `WEEK_DAYS`  object to an array:

```
export const WEEK_DAYS = [
    "Sun",
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat"
];
```